# Plot squares close to phylogeny taxa

Tags: r, phylogeny

I am trying to plot some coloured squares next to the terminal nodes of a phylogeny. However, I can't get the squares close to the terminal nodes. I think this is something to do with the taxa labels - despite having them turned off.

I plan to plot columns of squares after each other, which is why I can't use tip.labels with square characters.

here is my test function:

```
.squares = function(colour, start_point, n){
    colour = colour[length(colour):1]

    inc = 200
    ## Plot either points or rectangles. Dependant on arugment
    rect(start_point, 0.5:(n-0.5), start_point+inc, 
         1.5:(n+0.5), col = colour)
    start_point = start_point + inc ## inc is the width of each box. 
    start_point
}
```

And here is the test code:

```
library(ape)

n = 20
tree = rcoal(n, tip.label = letters[1:n])
t = plot(tree, show.tip.label = FALSE, no.margin = TRUE)

abline(v = t$x.lim[2], col = "red", lwd = 5)
.squares(rep("red", 20), start_point = t$x.lim[2], n = n)
```

Which gives:

[image]

I can't figure out how to close the gap between the squares and the terminal nodes.

Any direction would be appreciated. Since I will also be plotting multiple columns of squares, It would be helpful to know how I could add more columns without going into the margins.

thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. I tried your code and the red rectangles were right near the terminal nodes. No gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce your bug either (the horizontal line is added properly at the tips limit).

However, your problem seems really similar to posts on [Liam Revell's excellent blog](http://blog.phytools.org/). Have a look at [this code](http://blog.phytools.org/2018/02/annotating-plotted-phylogeny-with.html), [that one](http://blog.phytools.org/2018/02/plotting-tree-with-grid-of.html) or even better, [this final one](http://blog.phytools.org/2018/02/function-to-graph-discrete-character.html).

In your case, you could use something like that:

```
## phytools package
library(phytools)

## The tree
n = 20
tree = rcoal(n, tip.label = letters[1:n])

## The data
data <- data.frame(rep(1, n), rep(2, n))
colnames(data) <- c("Something", "SomethingElse")

## The plot (using a near 0 font size plot)
object <- plotTree.datamatrix(tree, data, sep=0, srt=70, yexp=1.05, fsize=0.0001)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! turns out my issue was due to having an old version of phytools. Once I updated the package I no longer had the gap.